# React & Node: Cookie has been rejected for invalid domain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, nginx, cookies

I have made a website using Node for server and Next for front-end. When I login, I make a request with these headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://loop.herbievine.com
server: nginx
set-cookie: lid=s%3AF4sw6csUWeU-nytZoR5w6nrkR_4gbpd2.zt5brbuuedQiyurZOB4Hn%2FSpRa8JqtrlYhY5AHxs9Yk; Domain=https://loop.herbievine.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Apr 2021 15:11:56 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Lax
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubdomains
vary: Origin
x-powered-by: Express
```

See I get a `set-cookie` header back. In the console, I see `Cookie “lid” has been rejected for invalid domain.`

On my server, I initialize the cookie with redis like so:

```js
session({
    name: COOKIE_NAME,
    store: new Store({
        client: redis,
        disableTouch: true
    }),
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        sameSite: 'lax',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
        domain: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN // this being set to https://loop.herbievine.com
    },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false
})
```

So why is this failing? Is there an additional setting to use?

Btw, I'm using Vercel + Cloudflare for all DNS settings, and server is running in a VPS + dokku on Digital Ocean

Comment: Shouldn't it be `loop.herbievine.com` instead of `https://loop.herbievine.com` in the domain?

Comment: I think that may have worked also... Changed it to .herbievine.com and that worked . But loop.herbievine.com might be better. ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue seems to be you using url instead of a domain. You should use domain `loop.herbievine.com` instead of `https://loop.herbievine.com`.

If you would like to share cookies with other sub domains then you will use the domain as `.herbievine.com`

Comment: Well weirdly I changed it back to `loop.herbievine.com` but I get the same error... I guess I'm sticking with `.herbievine.com`

Comment: for `localhost:3000`, you can use `.localhost`. i tried it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-client-cookies